# Can't bind to 'videoId' since it isn't a known property of 'youtube-player'

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube, ionic3, angular5

I am using Ionic 3 and Angular 5. I am embedding the Youtube videos in my application and to do so , I am using `ngx-youtube-player`. But it is giving me errors:

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'videoId' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'youtube-player'.
>   1. If 'youtube-player' is an Angular component and it has 'videoId' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'youtube-player' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>           
>            ][videoId]="fetch.video_id_" (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
>                         (change)="onStateChange($event)">
>           
>            [ERROR ->])
>       at JitCompiler._compileComponents (vendor.js:114542)
>       at vendor.js:114412
>       at Object.then (vendor.js:81363)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js:114411)

My app.module.ts is:

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';
import { YoutubePlayerModule } from 'ngx-youtube-player';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { TabPage } from '../pages/tab/tab';
import {VgCoreModule} from 'videogular2/core';
import {VgControlsModule} from 'videogular2/controls';
import {VgOverlayPlayModule} from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import {VgBufferingModule} from 'videogular2/buffering';
// import {SingleMediaPlayer} from './single-media-player';  
//-----------My own changes------------
import { ApiProvider } from '../providers/api/api';
// import {SingleMediaPlayer} from './single-media-player';
import { VideosPage } from '../pages/videos/videos';
import { VideosPageModule } from '../pages/videos/videos.module'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
//.............
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    TabPage,
    // SingleMediaPlayer
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, YoutubePlayerModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
    VgCoreModule,
    VgControlsModule,
    VgOverlayPlayModule,
    VgBufferingModule,VideosPageModule,HttpClientModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    TabPage,VideosPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My video.component.ts is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiProvider } from './../../providers/api/api';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Model } from '../Model/Model';

/**
 * Generated class for the VideosPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-videos',
  templateUrl: 'videos.html',
})
export class VideosPage { 
    videos: Model;
    player:any;sanitizer:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public modalCtrl: ModalController,public apiProvider: ApiProvider) {
  this.apiProvider.getVideos()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.videos = data;
        console.log(this.videos);
      });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad VideosPage');
  }
  videoplay(){ 
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('PlayPage');
    modal.present();
  }
     savePlayer(player) {
    this.player = player;
    console.log('player instance', player) 
  }
  onStateChange(event) {
    console.log('player state', event.data); 
  }

  mySplit = function(string, nb) {
    var array = string.split('|');
    return array[nb];
  }  
}
```

My videos.html is:

```
  <div class="song_wrapper">
      <div class="title">
        <h4>Featured</h4>
        <button ion-button outline round small no-margin="" text-capitalize="" color="lightgrey">View All</button>
      </div>



      <ion-slides slidesPerView="4.5" spaceBetween="10">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let fetch of videos?.data?.featured">
         <youtube-player
                            [videoId]="fetch.video_id_" (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
                        (change)="onStateChange($event)"></youtube-player>

         <!--  <img src="assets/removable/recently-played/Untitled-1-02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="play_icon"> -->
            <ion-icon name="videocam"></ion-icon>

          <p> {{fetch.category_name}}</p>
        </ion-slide>

      </ion-slides>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? - Edit: sorry I just saw you already mentioned angular 5

Comment: I am using Angular 5

Comment: Did you install v 0.1.0 of the lib? You cannot take the latest one

Comment: yes, I have installed `ngx-youtube-player@0.1.0`

Answer (score 5):

after installing by: `npm i ngx-youtube-player`

in your VideosPageModule you should add :

```
import { YoutubePlayerModule } from 'ngx-youtube-player';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ YoutubePlayerModule ]
})
```

check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-youtube-player?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @NSharma you did it in wrong way :
```BrowserModule,[ YoutubePlayerModule ]```, should be ```BrowserModule, YoutubePlayerModule``` ,

Comment: @NSharma you sould do these in your VideosPageModule not in app.module.ts .

Comment: It doesn't give any impact

Comment: @NSharma see error says that doesn't know the youtube-player tag, it means you didn't import it in your module. if your video component is using VideosPageModule then you should import it here and there is no problem any more, i think you are doing something wrong. in your app module you imported VideosPageModule are your video component is imported in VideosPageModule?

Comment: Hey Fateme, Thank you very much :) . I had imported `YoutubePlayerModule` in Videos.Module.ts and it is working now. 

I am posting `Videos.Module.ts` for future readers:

`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { YoutubePlayerModule } from 'ngx-youtube-player';

import { VideosPage } from './videos';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VideosPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(VideosPage),YoutubePlayerModule
  ],
})
export class VideosPageModule {}
 `